# How to upload image to canvas and draw squares on it and get the squares' coordinates

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to upload an image to canvas and draw squares on it and get the squares' coordinates to send it to the backend for keys identification.

But something not right, I can't draw squares on my images.

This is my javascript which I use:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var rect = {};
var drag = false;
var imageObj = null;

function init() {
    imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function () { ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0); };
    imageObj.src = 
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
}

function mouseDown(e) {
    rect.startX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    rect.startY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    drag = true;
}

function mouseUp() { drag = false; }

function mouseMove(e) {
    if (drag) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
        rect.w = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
        rect.h = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        ctx.strokeRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
    }
}
//
init();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('imageLoader').onchange = function(e) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = draw;
  img.onerror = failed;
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
};
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas.width = this.width;
  canvas.height = this.height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
}
function failed() {
  console.error("The provided file couldn't be loaded as an Image media");
}
```

and HTML:

```
 <canvas id="canvas" ></canvas>
 <input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader"/>
```

Comment: "But something not right" Probably, but you did not tell us what that "something" is. Please take the time to explain what is going wrong, with appropriate error messages, if necessary.

Comment: @spender image do not upload on canvas. And my square drawing script stops working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to assign the image to imageObj.

```
function draw() {
  canvas.width = this.width;
  canvas.height = this.height;
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);

  imageObj = this; //here
}
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/yv4oabjd/)